# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed - Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to make a delete route for my API but I'm encountering a problem. Whenever I hit the delete route I get an error which is `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`. I'm trying to delete a model if the delete route is hit. I have done `makemigrations` and `migrate` but there were no changes. Example of my code is like this:

```
class RandomAPIView(APIView):
    def delete(self, request, id, format=None):
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
        product.delete()
        return Response({'Success':'Product has been deleted'})
```

product in models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using django-rest-framework's serializers and viewsets to achieve this. ([RTFM](https://blog.serverfault.com/2010/10/13/1306724710/))

```py
## serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"

## views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins

# below subclassing is done to only allow deletion, 
# u can also use `viewsets.ModelViewSet` to allow all operations
# such as `list`, `create`, etc.
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.GenericAPIView, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

[Reference to DRF's docs.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)